# Wrong faces being seperated from one another after unwrap

Tags: faces, uv-image-editor

Some faces that are connected through 'unseemed' edges still separate from the rest of the island when I use unwrap

If you look at the attacked image, the left most edge of the selected face was not set to have a seem so it should be connected to the rest of the island. But if you look at the UV window on the left you can see it was unwrapped as a single island off in the corner.

Does anyone know why this is happening?

.[image]

Answer (score 1):

Under UV mapping/Smart UV project/ Change the angle limit to something like 40 and run it again. Or a value like 80

Comment: I have been adjusting the angle limit between 1-89 and it has not been fixing the problem. Also, I have noticed that even though I have keep aspect/ratio enabled there are certain parts that are much much larger than need be and then the opposite for the larger pieces.

Comment: So I think I have fixed the issue by using the Unwrap option in the UV window (I have no idea what the difference is but it is working now) Still, the aspect ratio is way off.